# Migrating Xamarin.Forms Android app to AndroidX support packages

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, androidx

I have a Xamarin.Forms Android project, am I'm trying migrate from the old Android support packages to AndroidX.  The migrate seems to work, and I end up having to add a reference to the AndroidX media package during compile.

The issue is that when I try to actually run the app, I get the exception

`System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to convert instance of type 'Android.Widget.RelativeLayout' to type 'AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar'.'`

from the `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.OnCreate`.  My `MainActivity` class subclasses `FormsAppCompatActivity` and `MainActivity`'s `OnCreate` immediately calls the base `OnCreate`.  Visual Studio says the exception is from external code, so it doesn't show me anything.

The `OnStart` and `OnResume` overrides in my `MainActivity` are called and finish fine (its only one line of code configuring the CrossCurrentActivity plugin being used.

I'm at a loss as to how to track down the problem.  I suspect the issue is somewhere in one of the packages I'm using, my main suspect being the `Xam.Plugin.Iconize` since it hasn't been updated for a while, but we rely on it and I'm not really sure how to prove where the issue is.

Comment: Delete the bin and obj folders in your applcation folders. Delete the actual app from the emulator by going into settings and apps and delete the application and redeploy.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I did all that, and still have the same issue.

Comment: Could you share a demo link? Because I cannot produce same error like you.

Answer (score 0):

I recently migrated to AndroidX and published the app. Users have been reporting a lot of crashes on start. I'm still figuring it out. Weird part is that, it works fine on some devices but crashes on some others.

I have noticed a few files in Android project still refer to the old 'Android Support' lib. Make sure you change them manually to AndroidX.

Check the Toolbar.xml and Tabbar.xml (Android proj>Resources>Layout). I had this in my app, which was still using android.support.v7......

[image]

I suggest to check in all the files and update manually where ever required.

Comment: Hi, did you fix your issue? I'm also having some troubles on certain Android devices. According to this guide, we can remove the Toolbar.xml and Tabbar.xml file? Have you tried this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/questions/forms5-migration